# how to get image from mysql database saved as blob by java,and show this image in browser with jsp

Tags: java

I want to retrive image from `mysql` database which is saved as blob by java and also want to display this image in browser I am trying to get image by `getBinaryStream()` and taking it in `InputStream` and also used `FileOutPutStream()`

but I am unaware how and which parameter I have to pass to `src` attribute of image tag to display image in browser

```
inputStream=rs.getBinaryStream("image");
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("abc.jpg");
int x;
while((x=inputStream.read())!=-1){
    fos.write(x);}
```

Comment: Make sure to add what you have tried so far and what went wrong. Also try to include output and/or errors so we can better help you. Remember, Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service, but there are a lot of helpful people here that are willing to take a look if you make an effort to explain your problem.

Answer (score 0):

simply write to response OutputStream :

```
InputStream in = rs.getBinaryStream("image");
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
int x;
while ((x = in.read()) != -1) {
     out.write(x);
}
out.flush();
out.close();
```